# Disable lookup standard validation

Tags: apex, lookup

I'm looking for some way to disable standard lookup validation that verify if the entered value exist (and throws `No matches found` if not).

When I enter some value from keyboard into the lookup input, I'd like to be able to create the new lookup value (if it doesn't exist). Any thoughts?

EDIT: The question is about visualforce page of course, I guess there's nothing that could be done on standard layout.

Comment: Bart, can you give us some more details? And perhaps some of your apex code?

Comment: Please see my edit, maybe it's more clear now. I don't think any code would be useful here.

Comment: This sounds like something you will have to make yourself using a visualforce page and an apex component as a lookup field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution:

1. Call JS function `j` on form save.
2. Execute JS Remoting method `m` from within `j`. Pass lookup field text `t` as a parameter.
3. In `@RemoteAction` check if the record with name `t` exists  and return result.
4. Now, depending on result you can call some `ActionFunction` to proceed, or cancel action, or even insert the `t` with JS Remoting as well.